# Dynamic Pricing based on demand and independent categorical variables

Tags: statistics, regression, prediction, analysis

I have search level data of a cab company;
[image]I have the variables presented above and also a lot of additional data related a search trip on their website.
example, it the session has led to a booking, this is with respect to 1 route..so it is either pickup from the route or drop to the route
Do not have the prices for reference, but at an ideal scenario, the price must be 700. when there is increase in demand and bookings the price must increase and the opposite
Please suggest me a statistical model or ML model or materials for reference

I tried taking the above data and computed coefficients for each category of the column
I did this by calculating normalized weight of standard deviations in each coulmn with respect to session count
I ran Linear regression on this data but model is not statistically significant